# cant connect to the correct localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I built a Netbeans project and connected it to the MySQL database through a localhost wamp server.

After an issue with the computer it was on, I had to move the project to my laptop.

When I run my project with my old database it can't find it; however, it finds the default databases (test, mysql, performance_schema, information_schema) from the phpmyadmin interface.

```
public void chackData(){
        try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mylibrary_db","root", "");
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM db ;";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            String s ="";
            while(rs.next()){
                 s = rs.getString("Db");
            System.out.println(s);
            }
    con.close();
```

can someone halp?

Comment: Can you access your old database on the laptop from the mysql client?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question seems stupid, but have you moved the old db on the laptop's mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you copied across the old database the passwords have become messed up or the old database deleted it during I assume is a new WAMP installation. If you have directly copied across the old database to a new wamp install then unless it was set up using the same passwords you will have an issue there and it is very hard to get them back if you dont know them already

Answer (score 0):

```
st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM db ;");
System.out.println("Connection stablished");
```

Comment: As a code-only answer this has been flagged as low-quality and will be probably deleted soon. Please add an explanation about what this code does.

Comment: @nalply [Code-only answers are not eligible for deletion. Please do not flag them.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, @ColonelThirtyTwo, but yours appeared in the low quality review queue. I didn't flag yours.